# show dynamic time with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to show the time which I have in my php variable with the help of Javascript

I am coding an online exam module, where I want to display the total elapsed time

say for example

`$time_elapsed` // contains the time taken till now from the start of the exam
And if I got a div say,

```
<div id="time"></div>
```

how can I show the dynamic running time with starting from `$time_elapsed` after load the window for each question

Please if you guys have an answer for this..

Thanks

Comment: Should the time only update after refresh of the page or every second like a clock? And when you answer a question, the page will be refreshed?

Comment: It should be like; if the total time elapsed is 10.15(10min 15sec)... it should show in the next page after loading the new question 10.16,10.17,10.18 after each sec elaps...yes the page will refresh after each refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can use the following code for the purpose

the javascript will be:

```
var Timer;
var TotalSeconds,TotalMins, secs;
var elapsedtime ;

function CreateTimer(TimerID, Time) {
        Timer = document.getElementById(TimerID);
        TotalSeconds = Time;
        elapsedtime = 0
        time = Time
        secs = TotalSeconds%60;
        TotalMins = Math.floor(TotalSeconds/60)
        UpdateTimer()
        window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
}

function Tick() {
if(TotalSeconds-elapsedtime>0)
{
    elapsedtime += 1;
    secs = (elapsedtime%60)-60;
    TotalMins = Math.floor(elapsedtime/60)
    UpdateTimer()
    window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
}
else
alert("time up")
}

function UpdateTimer() {
        Timer.innerHTML = TotalMins + ":" + secs;
}
```

nw create a html div where you want to show the running time.

**Html:**

```
<div id='timer' />
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = CreateTimer("timer", 5);</script>
```

give parameter the time limit. it will alert after time finishes.

and to get time after refresh of the page use html5's sessionStorage

visit  [Html5 Storage Doc](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)  to get more details. using this you can store intermediate values temporaryly/permanently locally and then access your values 
for storing values for a session

```
sessionStorage.getItem('label')
sessionStorage.setItem('value', 'label')
```

or store values permanently using

```
localStorage.getItem('label')
localStorage.setItem('value', 'label')
```

So you can store (temporarily) form data between multiple pages using html5 storage objects

Comment: I really don't see why providing someone with full code helps in any way what so ever, its certainly not going to help them learn.  They have not even posted any sort of attempt.  At most I think we should be giving pointers as to what they should be trying and let them actually try it for themselves.

Comment: Hello Jon, I posted this question. Please dont say like that...if I need to use the above code for my need then I have to learn each and every line of that, and the logic begin those lines, only then I can manipulate it according to my need. I think anyone in any context will have this same experience if they get a strip of code as an example before adapting to their need... Even you may not be able to  do anything if you dont know any JS before using this FULL CODE..

Answer (score 1):

This is how to display dynamic time. To use other php based starting time replace the line `time0 = new Date();` by `time0 =<?php echo $startTime;?>; which should be in ms since the epoch.`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>elapsed time demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var time0;
        function initTime() {
            time0 = new Date();
            window.setInterval("updateTime()", 1000);
        }
        function updateTime() {
            var timeNow = new Date();
            var deltas = (Number(timeNow) - Number(time0))/1000;
            var deltah = ("0"+String(Math.round(deltas / 3600))).substr(-2);
            deltah = deltah.substr(-2);
            deltas %= 3600;
            var deltam = ("0"+String(Math.round(deltas / 60))).substr(-2);
            deltas = ("0"+String(Math.round(deltas % 60))).substr(-2);
            document.getElementById("timedisplay").firstChild.data=deltah+":"+deltam+":"+deltas;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initTime();">
    <div> elapsed time <span id="timedisplay">00:00:00</span></div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: I dont get what exactly to give in time0 =<?php echo $startTime;?>; do you mean microsec that elapsed after starting the exam

Comment: can you please have an answer for this above comment

Answer (score 0):

Your php code should return the time elapsed at the point of loading the page, however, javascript will then take over and increment that time as time passes.

Comment: My question is how to implement it rather than how the flow should be,... I know when the php page refreshes the variable for time_elapsed will be send to the next question page, and then....how to take that variable to JS and do the rest?

Comment: Well have you tried anything so far?  We're not just going to write code for you.  Atleast show us that you have tried for yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the parameter to your JavaScript function which is display time

```
      function display_time(int time)
      {
        //your code for further integration
      }
```

You can send the parameter to JavaScript function using following way

```
      //call the function at the time display time
       display_time(<?php echo $time_elapsed ?>)
```